# Confusion about the proof of $\langle a^k\rangle=\langle a^{(n,k)}\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups

This theorem is from *[Contemporary Abstract Algebra](https://github.com/dtbinh/OpenCourse/blob/master/AbstractAlgebra/Contemporary%20Abstract%20Algebra%209th%20Joseph%20A.%20Gallian.pdf)* by J. Gallian page $78$.

> Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in a group and let $k$ be a positive
> integer. Then $\langle a^k\rangle=\langle a^{(n,k)}\rangle$.
>
> *Proof:* Let $d=\gcd(n,k)$ and let $k=dr$. Since $a^k=(a^d)^r$, $\langle a^k\rangle \subseteq \langle a^d\rangle$. Moreover, by Bezout's lemma, $d=ns+kt$, so $a^d=a^{ns+kt} \rightarrow a^d=e(a^k)^t$, so $\langle a^d\rangle \subseteq \langle a^k\rangle$. Then, $\langle a^k\rangle=\langle a^d\rangle=\langle a^{(n,k)}\rangle$.

**My question:** I agreed with the proof, but there is something stuck in my mind s.t If it holds for $d=(n,k)$, then could we say that $d=2(n,k)$ or $d=3(n,k)$ etc. because, this identity holds for every $d$ values if we use the definition of cyclic subgroup. Is my claim correct? If so, why don't we write $d=t(n,k)$ where $t \in \mathbb Z^{\geq1}$

**My second question** is that should $a$ be a generator? Because some sources say that $a$ has to be generator,for example [here page 64](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/5409004/mod_resource/content/2/John%20B.%20Fraleigh%2C%20Victor%20J.%20Katz%20-%20A%20first%20course%20in%20abstract%20algebra-Addison-Wesley%20%282003%29%20%281%29.pdf), but this book doesn't give such statement, so I confused at this point, as well.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

To the first question, you can not take $d=t(n,k)$ because of the first containment proved, as you wouldn’t have $k=dr$ with $r$ an interger. The other side would be true as bezouts gives a way to write all multiples of d.

Also $a$ doesn’t need to be a generator, this is true for every element in the group. But one cool consequence of this property if $a$ is a generator is that for every $j$ coprime with $n$, $a^j$ is also a generator.

Comment: some books for example "a first course in abstract algebra" by fraleigh says that $a$ must be generator.

Comment: please look at page 64 in [given link here](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/5409004/mod_resource/content/2/John%20B.%20Fraleigh%2C%20Victor%20J.%20Katz%20-%20A%20first%20course%20in%20abstract%20algebra-Addison-Wesley%20%282003%29%20%281%29.pdf)

Comment: when $k=3$, $n=8$, $(3,8)=1$, so $3=1 \times r \rightarrow r=3$, but we can also provide this by giving $t=3$ and $r=1$

Comment: the propositions in page 64 are for cyclic gruops (that means that they have generator) that is why they take $a$ as one. And you can teake some diferent values if t, as long as, $ t(n,k)$ divides $k$ the argument holds but no ** all** values of t for example in the case you say $t=5 $ or $t=1000$ both fail because 3 is not divisible by them

Comment: @FranAguayo I think you should edit your answer, because your last comment and answer dont match

Comment: what doesn't match, he ask in the coments why that book uses $a$ as a generator but the proposition in the question does not need to have $a$ as one